# How to print graph without using libraries while taking list input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu2Kd.png)

Hey forks i am new to stackoverflow and new to programming while i was learning i seen a interesting ctf where .I needed to print graph by taking input from user and printing in terminal without using libraries .

The problem i can print the first element in list properly but after that the loop starting from

```
lst = []
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))

# created loop for taking n of element
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input('Enter Value :'))  # taking input one by one using loop

    lst.append(ele)  # adding the to lst variable


def up () :
    for num in lst:
        temp = num
        for i in range(0,num):
            for v in range(0,temp):
                print('*',end='')
            print('/')
            temp = temp -1


up()

Out Put:-
Enter number of elements : 2
Enter Value = 3
Enter Value = 4
***/
**/
*/
****/
***/
**/
*/

need out put like:-
    *******/
    ******/
    *****/
    ****/
    ***/
    **/
    */
```

Comment: you probably want to first concatenate the strings to make one single string and then print that out, also usually you would pass arguments to the function rather than using global variables also what is the logic for the graph? you sum the user input and then just gradually decrease that sum which corresponds to number of `*`?

Comment: how does the input of `2 elements: values [3,4]` equate to an inverted triangle with 7 `*`s at the top?